# API Testing Using SoapUI vs Postman vs Runscope

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, api-testing

I'm new to using applications to test backend APIs. I've always just manually tested using the front-end applications. What I would like to do is to use an app that is designed specifically for backend API testing. So far, I've been directed to SoapUI, Postman, and Runscope. But I'm at a loss as I am more of a test analyst than I am a programmer, despite having experience automated testing in Selenium with JavaScript, Python and Ruby. Any suggestions? Thoughts? Warnings?

Comment: I'm quite confused what actually you are asking for. What's wrong with SoapUI or Postman?

Comment: I'm looking more for what others might thing of them. A chance for people to sell me on which one they prefer and why. There's nothing wrong with those two, I just don't know which one to use. That's all.

Comment: Ok. Backend APIs is a wide term including: SOAP Web services, REST Web services, JMS queues and many others, and some testing tools support testing multiple of them, and some focus on one of them. Which one are you going to test?

Answer (score 2):

[Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/radar/xj5jdktq7m0r) provides a Web UI for creating tests. There is no code to write for standard assertions.  You can write more complex assertions using Javascript.

It is a cloud based service, which allows tests to be run from data centers around the world, which is useful when testing response times.  You can also use our local agent to test APIs that are behind your firewall.

Individual test steps can be linked together with variables allowing you to take data from the first API request and use it as a parameter for the next request.

Runscope tests can be integrated with [Ghost Inspector](https://www.runscope.com/ghostinspector) to allow tests that combine both API and Web UI testing.

Disclaimer: I work as a developer advocate for Runscope.

Answer (score 1):

For simple user-friendly tool to test REST API, POSTMan is a great tool. It is easy to use. And, best for smoke testing. You can create request quickly. However, since you have some experience in automated testing. I would recommend to have automated test using JUnit. Basically, you need three thing to create automated test:

- Create Http Client.
- Expected response data object
- Junit test

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations. I had not thought about JUnit either.